# Realm android - RealmResults to List<String>

Tags: android, database, forms, list, realm

I have 2 models that are being synced from a Web app, these are catalogs for new items creation (spinner options) and all of these are dinamic depending the client ID.

Area Model:

```
public class Area extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int ID;
    private String Nombre;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Area toUnmanaged(Realm realm) {
        return isManaged() ? realm.copyFromRealm(this) : this;
    }
}
```

Ubicacion model:

```
public class Ubicacion extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int ID;
    private String Nombre;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Ubicacion toUnmanaged(Realm realm) {
        return isManaged() ? realm.copyFromRealm(this) : this;
    }
}
```

I already have these information on my database, so Realm is not my problem, I'm using [Form Master](https://github.com/adib2149/FormMaster) library and it requires a `List<String>` for Spinner options, how i can convert the `RealmResult` to a `List<String>`??
I only need the property **Nombre** of both models.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is this:

```
RealmResults<Area> areas = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    .where(Area.class).findAll();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(areas.size());
for (int i = 0; i < areas.size(); i++) {
    names.add(areas.get(i).getNombre());
}
```